# nested objects with class-transformer's plainToClass fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class-transformer

I'm playing with [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) node.

Based on [their example here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects), I have this code

```
import { Type, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import 'reflect-metadata';



export class Album {
  id: number;

  name: string;

  @Type(() => Photo)
  photos: Photo[];
}

export class Photo {
  id: number;
  filename: string;
}

const albumJson = {
  id:12,
  name:"album",
  photos:[
    {
      id:01,
      filename:"photo1.jpg"
    }
  ]
}

let album = plainToClass(Album, albumJson);
```

But it does not work : I get this error:

> Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an
> expression.   Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'Object'. @Type(() => Photo)

Can someone explain me what's wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was because tsconfig.json needed

```
"experimentalDecorators": true
```